# Difference between 'env' output and 'env -i bash -lc "env" '

Tags: bash, environment-variables, env

I am interested in finding the difference in environment variables from a clean login after some commands with the current environment.

I thought that starting a new interactive login shell (bash) should contain the environment immediately after sshing to the machine, but I am seeing a difference between running

```
env
```

immediately after sshing to the machine and then running

```
env -i bash -lc "env"
```

After some googling and reading of man pages I am still not sure what the source of the difference is. What are some possible sources of this difference?

edit 1: still showing differences with `env -i bash -ilc "env"`

example diff

```
3d2
< TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
5,11d3
< SHELL=/bin/bash
< TERM=xterm-256color
< TMPDIR=/var/folders/zx/jf775lqj7ml84vbgnr9rq7v80000gn/T/
< Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.VKm2gsWcqs/Render
< USER=username
< SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Co4UXQRSmI/Listeners
< __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
17,20d8
< LANG=en_US.UTF-8
< ITERM_PROFILE=Default
< XPC_FLAGS=0x0
< XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
22,25d9
< COLORFGBG=7;0
< HOME=/Users/username
< ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0
< LOGNAME=username
```

Comment: Vaguely interesting, but not really a programming question.  Nominating for migration to https://superuser.com/

Comment: `iterm` is clearly setting some of those. `ssh` is setting at least one of them.

Comment: @tripleee fair enough, now that I look there I guess it is slightly more appropriate, though I do wonder where the line is between parts of a shell script and "programming" (A discussion for the meta I suppose)

Comment: @EtanReisner That makes sense, I think was so focused on looking at all the various dot files, etc.

Comment: What you should probably do is see if `env -i iterm` (and then running `env`) differs from `env -i bash -ilc env`. To see what environment variables are coming from your desktop environment (if any).

Answer (score 1):

You're going from an interactive shell to a non-interactive shell, so you're going to potentially process different startup files.

Comment: I see, though I am still finding differences if I use `env -i bash -ilc "env"`

Comment: @user1984528 What differences, specifically, do you see between your normal environment and `env -i bash -ilc 'env'`?

Comment: @EtanReisner edited post to show some specific output